# How to install Cabal

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I have downloaded the cabal-install-1.20.0.1.tar.gz directory. But am unsure what to do with it? Opening it up there is just a bunch of files, there is no installer etc. I found an old guide but it is from 2011 and is now obsolete, any help?

Comment: Just grab the haskell platform, it comes with cabal and what amounts to a standard library.

Comment: I cannot do that as it is my University System not mine/

Comment: Do you already have GHC installed?  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: The system has "The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1" and is running Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: It seems odd that cabal wouldn't already be installed on the system.  Are you sure that `which cabal` doesn't find it?  If not, I would recommend downloading it from http://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html, where you can grab a pre-built binary for linux, or you can download the source package which comes with a bootstrap.sh file for grabbing all the dependencies it needs to build.  You'll have to follow the instructions in any README and INSTALL files. If you get stuck on a particular step edit your question with how far you got and what steps you followed

Answer (score 2):

How you install Cabal depends on how your system is set up.  Cabal definitely requires a working compiler to install.  So you have a few options, and some of them are more preferred than others:

If you don't have a compiler, get GHC and the Haskell Platform.  The Haskell Platform is a collection of important and useful libraries for Haskell.  The Haskell Platform is the "batteries included" distribution -- this is the one you want if you want your Haskell system to "just work."

If you already have a compiler, but you don't have Cabal, you can install Cabal by running the bootstrap.sh script in the tar file you downloaded.  You can also do it by running:

```
runhaskell Setup configure --user
runhaskell Setup build
runhaskell Setup install
```

inside the cabal-1.20 directory.  Notice that I passed in a --user flag.  This lets you install Cabal just for your user.  If you are unable to install to the system, you will want to use this last option.

I am not actually sure that Cabal 1.20 will install with a compiler as old as GHC-7.4.1.  If it doesn't work, you can actually get GHC-7.6.3 (or even 7.8) installed in your user directory.  The GHC binary linux installer uses the configure/make/install system, so you can pass in a --prefix.  If you go this route, I would advise using your new GHC to build the Haskell Platform (which also accepts a --prefix option).  So doing that would look something like:

```
<download ghc-7.6.3 tar file from http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3#x86linux>
<untar the ghc tar file>
$ cd <the ghc directory>
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
$ make install
$ cd ..
<download haskell platform source from http://www.haskell.org/platform/download/2013.2.0.0/haskell-platform-2013.2.0.0.tar.gz>
<untar the haskell platform tar file>
$ cd <the haskell-platform directory>
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME
$ make
$ make install
```

And then you would have to edit your path so that "$HOME/bin/" comes before "/bin"

Comment: 'code'~$ runhaskell Setup configure

<command line>:
    Could not find module `Setup'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
'code'

Comment: Are you inside the cabal-1.20.0.1 directory?

Comment: Yes but now I get: Configuring cabal-install-1.20.0.1...
Setup: At least the following dependencies are missing:
Cabal >=1.20.0 && <1.21, HTTP >=4000.2.5 && <4000.3

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to install Cabal-1.20 with GHC 7.4.1 (at least not without doing a *lot* of work, if it's even possible).  You should install a newer GHC into your home directory, using the --prefix option, and put the newer GHC into your path, and use that to build the haskell platform.

Comment: Sorry I am unsure on how to do this. What command installs a new GHC?

Comment: See the answer for a summary

Comment: I get: bash: ./configure: Permission denied 
when running "./configure --prefix=$HOME"

Comment: You need to get help from your system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a file named `bootstrap.sh` in the tarball. Run it to install cabal-install.

Comment: ~/cabal-install-1.20.0.1$ bootstrap.sh
bootstrap.sh: command not found

Comment: @user3641668 Most distributions' default shell configuration do not include `.` in their `PATH` for security reasons. You can try `./bootstrap.sh`. It's possible that--again for security reasons--you will need to mark `bootstrap.sh` as executable first by running `chmod +x bootstrap.sh`.